# Get multiple documents at once from change stream in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on Python and MongoDB Change streams. I am using PyMongo library. I have written the following code:

```
change_stream = self.client.watch(pipeline=pipeline, full_document='updateLookup', batch_size=100_000, resume_after=resume_token)            
logging.debug('.. debugging code ..')
for document in change_stream:
    resume_token = change_stream.resume_token
    logging.debug(resume_token)
    logging.debug(document['operationType'])
```

The problem is that if multiple documents are inserted at once in MongoDB, I get documents one by one in my code when i iterate over the change stream. Is there any way that I can get multiple documents from change stream in only one iteration so that I can process multiple documents at once instead of processing them one by one?